# Depth First Search Using Stack in Python

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I have implemented a depth first search using a stack (in a separate class). Any suggestions please on improvements for the below code:

```
class Stack:
    """(LIFO) queuing policy implemented using python list."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def push(self, item):
        """Push 'item' onto the stack."""
        self.list.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        """Pop the most recently pushed item from the stack."""
        return self.list.pop()

    def top(self):
        """Return the last element."""
        return self.list[-1]

    def is_empty(self):
        """Returns true if the stack is empty."""
        return len(self.list) == 0


def depth_first_search(graph, start):
    stack = Stack()
    stack.push(start)
    path = []

    while not stack.is_empty():
        vertex = stack.pop()
        if vertex in path:
            continue
        path.append(vertex)
        for neighbor in graph[vertex]:
            stack.push(neighbor)

    return path


def main():
    adjacency_matrix = {
        1: [2, 3],
        2: [4, 5],
        3: [5],
        4: [6],
        5: [6],
        6: [7],
        7: []
    }
    dfs_path = depth_first_search(adjacency_matrix, 1)
    print(dfs_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lists in Python are already stacks. It would be better if you used a raw `list` as people are more familiar with `list`s then a custom `Stack` class.

When using a plain Python list the `while` loop can take advantage of lists being truthy if they have items. This allows you to do `while stack:` instead.

I would prefer this to be a generator function as we likely won't need the entire DFS path. `path` can then be a `set` for \$O(1)\$ lookup rather than a list with \$O(n)\$ lookup. ("`if vertex in path:`")

```py
def depth_first_search(graph, start):
    stack = [start]
    visited = set()
    while stack:
        vertex = stack.pop()
        if vertex in visited:
            continue
        yield vertex
        visited.add(vertex)
        for neighbor in graph[vertex]:
            stack.append(neighbor)
```

Comment: Small clarification: the reason I've used a separate `Stack` class is because *DFS* uses stack. Although python lists are essentially stacks, I though it would be better if I'm explicit about it.

Answer (score 1):

Since Saurabh mentioned he wanted to be explicit:

```
from typing import Any 

Stack = list[Any]

def depth_first_search(graph, start) -> Iterator:
    stack : Stack = [start]
    visited = set()
    while stack:
        vertex = stack.pop()
        if vertex in visited:
            continue
        yield vertex
        visited.add(vertex)
        for neighbor in graph[vertex]:
            stack.append(neighbor)
```

though it might look superficial I think it is really nice to have `Stack` explicitly telling the user that the current list with start is a `Stack`. So we get double explicitness from the type definition and the initialization of your stack - with no user defined stacks.

---

Edit:

Comment from [Peilonrayz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42401):

> if you want a new type you'd have to inherit from `list` - `class Stack(list): pass` or `Stack = type("Stack", (list,), {})`.